# i can not push the notification ? with this code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, push-notification

i build a dialog to show and push a notification  but it can not appears

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Later", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//----------------------------//

        NotificationCompat.Builder   mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ProfileNavigationDrawer.this);
        mNotification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.start);
        mNotification.setTicker("Trip Name");
        mNotification.setContentTitle("Click to Start your Trip");
        mNotification.setContentText("Click to Appear");


        mNotification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        Toast.makeText(ProfileNavigationDrawer.this, "Later Clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
});
```

Comment: You didn't call the method to show notification.

Comment: the code is inside the action of the button

Comment: put that code too.

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: add this code below Toast:  NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification.build());

Answer (score 0):

Your final code

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Later", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder   mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ProfileNavigationDrawer.this);
    mNotification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.start);
    mNotification.setTicker("Trip Name");
    mNotification.setContentTitle("Click to Start your Trip");
    mNotification.setContentText("Click to Appear");


    mNotification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    Toast.makeText(ProfileNavigationDrawer.this, "Later Clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification.build());



}
});
```